# How to get a while loop in C# to print on a single line

Tags: c#

This is for a homework assignment, and while I've found some answers on getting the console to write line in the output, they've either been for a different programming language or affected how the console writes the out put vertically.

My code

```
int i=1
while (i<22)
{
  if (i%2 ==1)
    Console.WriteLine(i);
  Console.WriteLine("\t");
  i++;
}
```

The tutorials I've found still have everything printing vertically. Can I get them to print horizontally

Comment: There is `Console.Write(...)` method

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Console.Write(...)` method as Vasily mentions above, or you could create the output string inside a for loop then output the string as a line. I have also changed it to use an inline statement and a for loop. ie:

```
int i=1;
string output="";

for(int count = 0; count < 22; count++) {
    output += i % 2 == 1 ? i : "\t"; }

console.WriteLine(output);
```

The advantage if you used the `Console.Write()` command in the above code would be shortened by a line, I just prefer to get my ducks in a row before outputting anything.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of recursive function

```
private void Print(int counter, int end)
{
    if (counter > end)
        return;

    if (counter % 2 == 1)
        Console.Write(counter);

    Console.Write("\t");
    counter++;
    Print(counter, end);
}
```

then call `Print(1,22)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int i = 1;
while (i < 22)
{
    if (i % 2 == 1)
        Console.Write(i+"\t");
        
    i++;
}
```

Output:  1    3   5   7   9   11   13   15   17   19   21